# Unable to create deployment for ecs using aws cli (The deployment specifies that the revision is a null file, but the revision provided is a zip file)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy (using Blue/Green deployment controller) a revision of my APIs. When i do this manually by creating an updated task revision and updating the service, this works fine. But when i try using the CLI, when i push the appspec.yml file to s3 i get a create-deployment command returned back. And when i try to trigger deployment using this command, the triggered deployment shows in the deployments section but is failed and the error i see is **The deployment specifies that the revision is a null file, but the revision provided is a zip file.** Please help.

Comment: is there any progress about this issue?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution? we are currently facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I moved away from storing it as a zip file and stored as a normal json only and it worked for me.